# Using Transformations to transform a HashMap into a List

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, transformation, android-architecture-components

So, I have a viewmodel that will store a HashMap with different products, this hashmap will be updated/deleted/created , and then I need to transform this hashmap into a list so in my UI I just return the modified List

Now, this is my viewmodel

```
class SharedViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val cartHashMap = MutableLiveData<HashMap<String,Cart>>()
    private var sharedHashMap = HashMap<String,Cart>()

fun setProductSelectedHashMap(productId:String,productSelected:Cart){
        sharedHashMap[productId] = productSelected
        cartHashMap.value = sharedHashMap
    }

    fun removeSelectedProduct(productId:String){
        sharedHashMap.remove(productId)
        cartHashMap.value = sharedHashMap
    }

    fun updateSelectedHashMap(productId:String,quantity:Int){
        val productCartSelected = sharedHashMap[productId]
        productCartSelected?.quantity = quantity
        sharedHashMap[productId] = productCartSelected!!
        cartHashMap.value = sharedHashMap
    }

}
```

So, here I have a hashmap that I update from another source , this hashmap will contain a list of products that will be removed, updated or added to this map.

Each time this happens, I want to return to my view with livedata a list that will contain exactly what my HashMap contains, but I'm finding this a way confusing on how to transform this data into a list with Transformations

I have tried this

```
val getCart: LiveData<HashMap<String,Cart>> = Transformations.switchMap(cartHashMap, ::someFunc)
    private fun someFunc(myCartHash: HashMap<String,Cart>) = mutableListOf(myCartHash.values)
```

But `::someFunc` gives me an error, I use switchMap since the data will be constantly changing and will not be maped once, I only want to return my updated hashmap as a list with the same value that my hashmap contains.

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to use `Transformations.map` rather than `switchMap` as prior method provides `type T-> R` conversion which is your case rather than `T-> LiveData<R>`

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by doing it like this

```
 val getCart: LiveData<MutableList<Cart>> = Transformations.switchMap(cartHashMap) {
        liveData(context = viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
           emit(it.values.toMutableList())
        }
    }
```